# I was installing virtualbox and had a problem installing virtualbox -qt

Tags: package-management, virtualbox, dependencies

I wanted to install virtualbox and I had to install virtualbox -qt and there was a problem with packages

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 virtualbox : Depends: libgsoap-2.8.91 but it is not installable
              Depends: libsdl1.2debian (>= 1.2.11) but it is not installable
              Depends: libvncserver1 (>= 0.9.10) but it is not installable
              Recommends: virtualbox-qt (= 6.1.6-dfsg-1) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: libqt5opengl5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.'''
```

Help me solve this problem on Ubuntu 20.04

Output of `apt policy virtualbox-qt`:

```
bogdan@bogdanbook:~$ apt policy virtualbox-qt 
virtualbox-qt:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 6.1.6-dfsg-1
  Version table:
    6.1.6-dfsg-1 500
      500 archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show the output of `apt policy virtualbox-qt`

Comment: 'bogdan@bogdanbook:~$ apt policy virtualbox-qt
virtualbox-qt:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 6.1.6-dfsg-1
  Version table:
     6.1.6-dfsg-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64 Packages'

Comment: please add `sudo apt update` to your question through [edit]

Comment: Thanks for the information. The output indicates that you do not have the `updates` or `security` repos enabled on your system, so only the old version of `virtualbox-qt` included in the original 20.04 release is available. The version available on an updated system is 6.1.38-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.20.04.1. Is there a reason your system is not configured to receive security and other updates?